# Accessing the softmax output of previous RNN state in Keras

Tags: deep-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network, softmax

The recurrence formula in my RNN is `h(t) = tanh(W.x(t) + U.h(t-1) + V.O(t-1) + b)`, where `O(t-1)` is the classification output (Softmax output) of the RNN at time `t-1`. How can I access this output at the next time step?

I guess I have to write a custom RNN, but I am a bit confused by all the recurrent functions in recurrent.py in Keras and I am not sure which parts should be modified.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the recurrent documentation on the keras homepage: https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/ and  maybe read the linked papers on the topic. Your question seems to me like a simple RNN Layer with softmax otuput. Keras then does the rest.

Comment: @ThomasPinetz Thanks for your comment. Well, I have not found anything useful. Apparently I need to go deep into the code (up to 5-6 level) to modify for my purpose :(, however the code is too confusing for me. I was hoping there could be a clever way to do this, because I need to have `O(t-1)` separately to do some computation on it and use for computing `h(t)`.